# Get SSL to work on Google Compute Engine with a VM Instance running a webserver (nginx)?

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine

I am a bit new to Google Compute engine and managed to get a webserver with nginx to work on my google domain and installed WordPress. HTTP access was working. Now I wanted to get HTTPS to work as well.

I noticed that I don't have SSL running and so I ended up using cloudflare, made necessary changes to my nginx server and also changed the nameserver for my webserver IP address on the Google Compute Engine. That works fine. Although, there are still some errors when accessing the IP address instead of the domain name (400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)).

So, I heard Google can do SSL on my google domain, but I am really stuck with the documentation, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl?authuser=2#upgrading_to_managed_ssl_certificates. It talks about Google App Engine and I haven't found a documentation to apply SSL certificates to my Google Compute Engine instance. Though, I added a custom domain there, but it points to a different IP address than my webserver on the Google Compute Engine. That surely can't be the right way?

Hence, does anyone know how I can get SSL from Google to work on my webserver using a VM instance on Google Compute Engine?

(Note to myself: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy to set up SSL on Compute Engine.

**STEP 1: Domain names**

Determine which domain names you want SSL certificates for. Typically you want two. The naked domain (example.com) and the zone www ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). Replace example.com with your actual domain name.

Note: Let's Encrypt will not issue SSL certificates for an IP address. This also means you cannot access your web server using SSL specifying an IP address instead of a domain name. Trying this will generate an error: https://my-ip-address.com

**STEP 2: Setup DNS**

Change your DNS servers to point directly to your Compute Engine instance reserved static IP address. At this point, do not use CloudFlare. Let's Encrypt will talk directly to your Nginx web server. Validate that each domain name is configured correctly and that you can access your site via HTTP (http://example.com and http://www.example.com).

The following instructions are OS dependant and are for Debian based systems such as Debian and Ubuntu. There are similar steps for CentOS, Red Hat, etc.

**STEP 3: Install Certbot**

Certbot is the software agent for Let's Encrypt. This requires Python3 to be installed on your system. Most Google Cloud instances have Python 3 installed.

Run the following commands on your VM instance:

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade -y
- sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx

**STEP 4: VPC Firewall**

Make sure that ports 80 and 443 are allowed in the Google Cloud VPC Firewall.

[Using firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)

**STEP 5: Issue the SSL Certificate**

Run the following command on your VM instance. Replace example.com with your domain names.

- sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

**Summary**

Your server now has SSL configured.  The SSL certificate will auto-renew. Provided that you do not change the domain names or DNS server settings, SSL will continuously function.

In the future, you may decide to offload SSL certificates to another service such as Cloudflare or a Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer. I recommend understanding how to set up SSL directly on your instance so that encryption is end-to-end. Then you can decide on SSL-offloading, caching, load balancing, auto-scaling, and more options.

Comment: Thanks. I have done "Full (strict) Encrypts end-to-end, but requires a trusted CA or Cloudflare Origin CA certificate on the server" on cloudflare already. I generated my certificates and add them in the nginx config file, together with the cloudflare certificate. - I thought that google does this in-house as well, and I don't need cloudflare?

Comment: @nolimits You are confusing SSL on your web server and SSL offloading and Caching Frontends. My answer covers setting up SSL on your Compute Engine instance since your goal is **Now I wanted to get HTTPS to work as well.**. And no, you do not need Cloudflare. CF does have benefits though. If you do not have SSL configured on your web server, then you need to set up Cloudflare correctly. Before offloading anything (SSL, caching, etc) your web server must be set up correctly.

Comment: Yes I probably confuse this. I don't know the difference. - I have SSL working on the IP address as well, but I forgot to mention that its "not valid". At the moment I get the "400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent" error when accessing the IP instead the name. I did use the cloudflare certificate (.crt and .key) and the end-to-end cloudflare certificate on the webserver. I added them in the server config file where I also re-route to HTTPS (ie 301, 302). I am confused about your method. What does it to? Where does it put the certificate on the server?

Comment: ...at step 2, can I just point Google's name servers to my IP? Do I have to make adjustments on my nginx server config file?

Comment: @nolimits - I do not know as you did not post your Nginx configuration in your question. In most cases, Nginx will work out of the box. However, in step 2, I mention verifying your domain names work correctly for HTTP. If they do not work, SSL will fail. Make whatever changes to Nginx are required to complete step 2.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what happens now. I got end-to-end encryption running but that only applied to the domain name. And as soon as I access the IP, the server says "nope". I will try using your way next week back at work. :) Thanks!